# Error when trying to compile chromium on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, cross-compiling, chromium

I am following [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176794/how-do-i-cross-compile-chromium-for-arm) to compile **Chromium Browser** and I successfully walked through each step but I get the following error at the 17th step: `gclient sync`:

```
mrgrj@mrgrj:~/chromium/buildhost/src$ gclient sync
Syncing projects:   4% ( 3/72) src/chrome/tools/test/reference_build/chrome_linSyncing projects:   5% ( 4/72) src/sdch/open-vcdiff                            Syncing projects: 100% (75/75), done.                                         

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/landmines.py' in '/home/mrgrj/chromium/buildhost'

________ running '/usr/bin/python src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --mode nacl_core_sdk sync --extract' in '/home/mrgrj/chromium/buildhost'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 59, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py", line 29, in Main
    import package_version
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/buildhost/src/native_client/build/package_version/package_version.py", line 40, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2313, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2299, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2056, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1528, in RunOnDeps
    self.RunHooksRecursively(self._options)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 983, in RunHooksRecursively
    hook, cwd=self.root.root_dir, always=True)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 293, in CheckCallAndFilterAndHeader
    return CheckCallAndFilter(args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 538, in CheckCallAndFilter
    rv, args, kwargs.get('cwd', None), None, None)
  File "/home/mrgrj/chromium/depot_tools/subprocess2.py", line 37, in __init__
    super(CalledProcessError, self).__init__(returncode, cmd, output=stdout)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output'
```

Any hints on how can I get rid of it ? I will update this post with any necesarry information that you'll need.

Comment: Which python version do you have? Update the python version to 2.7 or greater. It is strange that the module argparse isn't found.

Comment: That was the problem. I had Python 2.6 configured. After changing it to 2.7 it worked

Comment: python2.7 is the default  on ubuntu 14.04 so that makes no sense. If you are screwing around with the system python it won't end well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the python version to 2.7 or greater. One of the problems is that you don't have argparse which is on the newest version of python.